# Why does the value of "i" not change after executing "boolean t = true,b; b = (t || ((i++) == 0))"

Tags: java, boolean-logic

```java
  int i = 0;
  boolean t = true;
  boolean f = false, b;
  b = (t || ((i++) == 0));
  b = (f || ((i+=2) > 0));
  System.out.println(i);
```

After the above code is executed, the print result is 2, not 3, why?

I find "i" was 0 not 1 after "b = (t || ((i++) == 0))" executed by debuging.Well,I'm confused why "i++" not changes "i".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Well,I'm confused why "i++" not changes "i".

Because `i++` doesn't execute in the code you've provided.

In an expression of the form `a || b`, first `a` is evaluated, and if it's true (which it is in this case), the expression `b` *isn't* evaluated. This is known as *short-circuiting*.

This is described in [JLS section 15.24](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24).

If you change the code to use the non-short-circuited `|` operator instead, like this:

```
b = (t | ((i++) == 0));
```

... then it will evaluate both operands regardless.

Comment: I got it ! Thank you very much.